# change values of multiple elements in std::multimap by key

Tags: c++, multimap

I am using a `std::multimap`

```
std::multimap<string,string> map;
```

It contains elements below

```
1 2  
2 3
3 2
1 2
1 0
```

I want to replace all 1's and 2's by X. I searched in *google* for a long time, but didn't get the result. I tried like

```
for(it=mmap.begin();it!=mmap.end();it++)
{
   if(it->first == "1" || it->first == "2")
   {
     key = it->second;
     it.erase(it);
     mmap.insert(pair<string,string>("X",key));
   }
}
```

but ended up in wrong result . I understand the size varies each time and when we insert the element gets inserted at the end which in turn ends the for loop. any other way to come out of this?

Comment: That code won't compile.

Comment: See [`std::multimap::lower_bound()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) and the linked reference within that to `std::multimap::upper_bound()`. They will get the ranges you're looking for, though I question your desire to mod-the-map while enumerating it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying container while iterating it, it is bad.

I suggest you to store all values you want to replace, remove them, and place everything you want back.

Or just create new map with desired values

Answer (score 0):

> > I understand the size varies each time and when we insert the element gets inserted at the end

No it doesn't, it inserts a new element in such position as to preserve the ordering.

What you need to do is this.

```
// for "1"
while (auto I = mmap.lower_bound ("1"), I != mmap.end())
{
    mmap.insert(pair<string,string>("X",I->second));
    mmap.erase (I);
}

// Same for "2"
while (auto I = mmap.lower_bound ("2"), I != mmap.end())
{
    mmap.insert(pair<string,string>("X",I->second));
    mmap.erase (I);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want *both* of those `.end()`s to be `.upper_bound(..)`